# How to remove price column from woocommerce email?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on editing my customer emails from my woocommerce store. I have managed to remove the subtotal and total rows already, and I have managed to remove the word "Price" from the top row of the price column. However, no matter what I seem to try I cannot remove the actual column. I want the emails to only show the item name and quantity ordered.
I am running woocommerce v. 3.3.4 and the "stark" theme.
I have already overwritten the standard woocommerce email templates.
Below you can find the current contents of my "email-order-details.php" and "email-order-items.php" files.

Here is email-order-details.php

```
/**
 * Order details table shown in emails.
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version 3.3.1
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$text_align = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

do_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ); ?>

<h2>
    <?php
    if ( $sent_to_admin ) {
        $before = '<a class="link" href="' . esc_url( $order->get_edit_order_url() ) . '">';
        $after  = '</a>';
    } else {
        $before = '';
        $after  = '';
    }
    /* translators: %s: Order ID. */
    echo wp_kses_post( $before . sprintf( __( 'Order #%s', 'woocommerce' ) . $after . ' (<time datetime="%s">%s</time>)', $order->get_order_number(), $order->get_date_created()->format( 'c' ), wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ) );
    ?>
</h2>

<div style="margin-bottom: 40px;">
    <table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 100%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
<!--                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php #echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php #esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
 -->
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
            echo wc_get_email_order_items( $order, array( // WPCS: XSS ok.
                'show_sku'      => $sent_to_admin,
                'show_image'    => false,
                'image_size'    => array( 32, 32 ),
                'plain_text'    => $plain_text,
                'sent_to_admin' => $sent_to_admin,
            ) );
            ?>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <?php
#           $totals = $order->get_order_item_totals();

/*          if ( $totals ) {
                $i = 0;
                foreach ( $totals as $total ) {
                    $i++;
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['label'] ); ?></th>
                        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; <?php echo ( 1 === $i ) ? 'border-top-width: 4px;' : ''; ?>"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $total['value'] ); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
            }
*/          if ( $order->get_customer_note() ) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="td" scope="row" colspan="2" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Note:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                    <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php echo wp_kses_post( wptexturize( $order->get_customer_note() ) ); ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ); ?>
```

and here is email-order-items.php

```
/**
 * Email Order Items
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-items.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates/Emails
 * @version     3.2.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$text_align = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item ) :
    $product = $item->get_product();
    if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_visible', true, $item ) ) {
        ?>
        <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'order_item', $item, $order ) ); ?>">
            <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; word-wrap:break-word;"><?php

                // Show title/image etc
                if ( $show_image ) {
                    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', '<div style="margin-bottom: 5px"><img src="' . ( $product->get_image_id() ? current( wp_get_attachment_image_src( $product->get_image_id(), 'thumbnail' ) ) : wc_placeholder_img_src() ) . '" alt="' . esc_attr__( 'Product image', 'woocommerce' ) . '" height="' . esc_attr( $image_size[1] ) . '" width="' . esc_attr( $image_size[0] ) . '" style="vertical-align:middle; margin-' . ( is_rtl() ? 'left' : 'right' ) . ': 10px;" /></div>', $item );
                }

                // Product name
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item->get_name(), $item, false );

                // SKU
                if ( $show_sku && is_object( $product ) && $product->get_sku() ) {
                    echo ' (#' . $product->get_sku() . ')';
                }

                // allow other plugins to add additional product information here
                do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

                wc_display_item_meta( $item );

                // allow other plugins to add additional product information here
                do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

            ?></td>
            <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_order_item_quantity', $item->get_quantity(), $item ); ?></td>
            <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }

    if ( $show_purchase_note && is_object( $product ) && ( $purchase_note = $product->get_purchase_note() ) ) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo wpautop( do_shortcode( wp_kses_post( $purchase_note ) ) ); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here is a screenshot of what the current email looks like using the template files above:
[Email sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KD4w.png)

Answer (score 2):

You've commented out the `th` element for price in `email-order-details.php`. You need to remove the matching `td` element from `email-order-items.php`. It's immediately before the closing `</tr>` tag.

This is the particular line in question:

```
<td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo $text_align; ?>; vertical-align:middle; border: 1px solid #eee; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal( $item ); ?></td>
```

Then, you need to change the colspan attribute of the purchase note section from 3 to 2. You've just removed one of the columns so 3 is no longer correct.